# PATH not set after SSH from MacBook to Windows

Tags: windows, ssh, powershell, mac

The goal is to start some jupyter notebooks remotely from my Macbook on my Windows machine, because of the GPU power.

I've installed the [OpenSSH server](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_install_firstuse) utility on my Windows machine and I am able to connect to it from the Macbook. Unfortunately if I type in `jupyter notebook` in the remote PowerShell it can not resolve the command `jupyter`. I assume that it does not set the PATH variable. However the %PATH% variable is set correctly and if I change the directory to `%ANACONDA_HOME%` it changes to the desired location.

But I don't know why it cannot find the `jupyter` command.

edit: The workaround to this issue is to go manually to the scripts folder of anaconda and start `activate base`, which is usually done by about_Profiles. BTW: If I connect via ssh, variables such as `$PROFILE` or `$PSHOME` are not set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure your default shell in OpenSSH server. By default you get a `cmd` window, not a PowerShell one. To set it to PowerShell, you can run the following command from and elevated PowerShell window on the Windows server:

```
New-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\OpenSSH" -Name DefaultShell -Value "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -PropertyType String -Force
```

All the default `$env:` variables should load the next time you connect over SSH.

For more information, see the Microsoft documentation [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_server_configuration).